# grouping data by weeks laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

I've small website to follow the progress of someone reading for each week.
so, I've created table('books') with these fields 
id,book,author,category,pages,done

I need to do like this 
First()->7 elements insert into first week
First()->8-14 elements insert into second week
And so on

Comment: Share some reproducible input & output data.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not very clear to me what you're trying to accomplish or what code you need our help with. It would be clearer if you presented what you are currently trying and ask for help in fixing the issue. Check out SO's guide to asking questions for more assistance in updating your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to know how to get your database online since you tagged it php mysql?

First you need to connect to your database, you can google this.
Then you want to pass a sql query SELECT * FROM books WHERE (some clause)
Followed by a fetch_mysql() and some html to format the display.

This is as much guess work I can do based on your question.